# UIPickerView accessiblityLabelForComponent not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipickerview

I am trying to set accessibility label for `UIPickerView` component, but the delegate method is never called. What's more, UIInspector shows the pickerView is not accessible, but it has the label actually set.

The dataSource/delegate methods are fired. Only the `UIAccessibilityDelegate` is not.

Tested on xcode 10.1 iOS 12.1 simulator

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewAccessibilityDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.isAccessibilityElement = true
        pickerView.accessibilityLabel = "TESTAccLabel"
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(component) - \(row)"
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, accessibilityLabelForComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "TODO:JS"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do u found any solution for this ?